# 2D line color gradient from a third variable

Tags: scilab

I have created a code to visualize the deformation as well as the stress in a stress structure. So far so good.
The strain is displayed as a function of the x and y of each element. The stress is computed in a vector named "contraintes".
I would like to be able to create a color gradient on each line directly related to the value of the stress.

I am actually trying to plot a 2D line plot of two arrays (x and y) with color as a function of a third array (contraintes) with eventually a colorbar.

Thanks for your help.

Edit : I've made this to color each line from a jetcolormap but when I add a colorbar, the color does not match with my jetcolormap.

```
colorbar(min(contraintes),max(contraintes),[1,11]);
colorspec=jetcolormap(11);

for e=1:nombre_ele
    x=[noeuds_coor_def(elements(e,1),1) noeuds_coor_def(elements(e,2),1)];
    y=[noeuds_coor_def(elements(e,1),2) noeuds_coor_def(elements(e,2),2)];
plot(x,y,'color', colorspec(e,:),'LineWidth',5);
end
```

Comment: so you want a contour plot?

Comment: This is what i'm talking about [example](http://personales.upv.es/~jmasia/Libro_ANSYS/img/1_EB-04/37-en.png) where the line color depends on the stress value from lower to higher.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xsegs function as in the example above:

```
 x=linspace(0,20,100);
 y=x^3-20*x^2;
 z=sqrt(x);
 clf;
 ncolors=128;
 gcf.color_map=hotcolormap(ncolors)
 xx=[x(1:$-1);x(2:$)];
 yy=[y(1:$-1);y(2:$)];
 zz=mean([z(1:$-1);z(2:$)],1);

 c=(ncolors-1)*(zz-min(zz))/(max(zz)-min(zz))+1;
 xsegs(xx,yy,c)
 gce().thickness=3;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i don't think it will make what i'm really talking about. This is what I'm looking for : [example](https://cdn3.f-cdn.com//files/download/80683264/f5f407.jpg)

Comment: Why not, your example can easily be done using the xsegs function